# Maintaining state outside React and "Replacing React-rendered children with a new root component." warning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am working on an application that only recently began to use React (replacing d3). It's built roughly along the MVC paradigm, where React is only used in (some of) the view, and therefore does not have some root React component whose state controls everything. In fact, almost all of our React components are stateless (only a few have small internal states for handling things that don't require updating the model).

So instead of having a root component with a controlling state, we have React components reporting actions through callbacks, which eventually update the model and trigger rerendering the view. As in, `ReactDom.render(<SomeComponent {...props} />, someElement);` where `props` has been created based on the new, updated model. Not everything in the view uses React (though we are working towards that goal), and not every React component is contained in any single root React component (and that will likely never change, if for no other reason than that our application sometimes uses multiple browser windows).

Is just calling `ReactDom.render` again with new props the correct way to update our React views in this situation? This seemed surprising to us, but it seemed to be what we were reading in the documentation etc. It certainly seemed to work. But today I added a new call to `ReactDom.render`, and now we get this warning in the console:

> Warning: render(...): Replacing React-rendered children with a new root component. If you intended to update the children of this node, you should instead have the existing children update their state and render the new components instead of calling ReactDOM.render.

We are only getting this with the new `ReactDom.render` call; numerous others before this one have not given us this warning. In fact, the code triggering this warning is something quite like this:

```
// selection is a d3 selection that has not been converted to React yet
// data includes the updated data for this object and its children
selection.each(function (data) {
    const someElement = d3.select(this).select('.some-class').node();
    ReactDom.render(
        <>
            {data.someChildren
                .map(toSomeProps)
                .map(someProps =>
                    <SomeComponent key={keyOf(someProps)} {...someProps} />
                )
            }
        </>,
        someElement
    );

    const anotherElement = d3.select(this).select('.another-class').node();
    const anotherProps = toAnotherProps(data);
    ReactDom.render(
        <AnotherComponent {...anotherProps} />,
        anotherElement
    );
});
```

(For those unfamiliar with d3, this is effectively taking an array of elements, finding particular subelements within them, and rendering React components inside those subelements. Eventually this will be migrated to just React.)

The `SomeComponent`s group is the new one, and the `AnotherComponent` has been there. I get the warning about `SomeComponent`, but not about `AnotherComponent`. Maybe it doesn't repeat the warnings for the two next to each other, but we never got the warning when `AnotherComponent` was the only part that was there.

The only notable difference that I can tell here is the use of `<>{...}</>` in the `SomeComponent` case, instead of a “real” wrapping component. Does that matter? And if so, *why?*

Comment: I included the [[tag:typescript]] and [[tag:d3]] tags because they are tangentially related (we're working in Typescript, d3 is being replaced), but really this question is about React. I hope I've tagged this right.

Comment: Have you tried replacing <></> with <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>? Not really sure where I'm going with this, but thought you could try it..

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD No, I haven't; I will.